# build function f(x) and get the result

Tags: math

I need to build a function:

```
f(220) = 0


f(115) = 30
```

so for every x that I pass to the function f(x), I will get the result between 0 to 30.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. What do you mean by every `x`? Does the value of `x` need to be between `115` and `220`? Also you need to mention if `f(x)` is supposed to be a linear function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about math, not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a linear relationship then:

```
 f(x) = 30 * (220 - x) / (220 - 115)
```